# lightning:datatable component cutting off actions drop down menu when it goes past the card and displays scrollbar instead

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

[image]I am having a problem using the lightning:datatable component that is contained in a lightning:card component. The actions on the table rows are getting cut off if it expands beyond the card instead of overlaying like it does for out of the box related list components. Any help or suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did the below post asnwer or help you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to your CSS.

```
.THIS .slds-scrollable_x
{overflow-y:visible!important;overflow-x:visible!important;}
.THIS .slds-scrollable_y
{overflow-y:visible!important;overflow-x:visible!important;}
```

Comment: please provide explanations when answering with code. thanks

Comment: Sure, the lightning:dataTable has slds-scrollable elements. The default styling on these elements hides the actions menu. Restyling them to always show content solves the OP's issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your post rather than commenting

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to set a minimum height on your lightning:datatable component. Please try to use the css below on your component.

```
.THIS .slds-scrollable_y {
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: The suggestion above did display the complete sub-menu but it leaves and extended space at the bottom of the card under the data table even when the actions are not open.

Comment: @JayeshBhatnagar did you find any workaround for extended space?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar problem in a custom table that used lightning:buttonMenu elements to show actions.

After a lot of banging our heads on a wall, we discovered that adding this code to a lightning:buttonMenu tag did the trick.  Interestingly enough, if you don't specify a menuAlignment attribute at all, it's the same as using menuAlignment="left"

```
menuAlignment="auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is WAAAY old, but this solution worked for me --

Add this to your component style:

```
.THIS lightning-button-menu{
margin-left: -15px;}
```