# actions popover is hidden in lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

[image]i am using plain `lightning:datatable` with actions column. but after click on action icon popover shows hidden in below row like image, [same issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209086/ligntning-datatables-actions-menu-hidden) but no solutions

**cmp**

```
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(item.rowdata))}">                                          
                                              <lightning:datatable keyField ="Id"
                                                         data="{!item.rowdata}" 
                                                         columns="{!v.tablecolumns }" 
                                                         onrowaction="{!c.handleEditrecord}"
                                                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                                                         />

                                     </aura:if>
```

**cmpcontroller.js**

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
 var Tableclumns= [
            {label: 'field1', fieldName: 'field1__c', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'field2', fieldName: 'field2__c', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'field3', fieldName: 'field3__c', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'field4', fieldName: 'field4__c', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'field5', fieldName: 'field5__c', type: 'text'},
            {type: 'action', typeAttributes : {label:'Edit',name:'edit_record'}}

        ]; 

        component.set("v.tablecolumns ",Tableclumns);  
}
```

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207411/lightningdatatable-actions-menu-is-hidden
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211012/lightningdatatable-component-cutting-off-actions-drop-down-menu-when-it-goes-pa

Comment: @Rodrigo no luck with above thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu isn't being clipped; it's empty.

`action` requires a `typeAttributes` where `rowActions` is a list. This is in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation):

```
var actions = [
    { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' },
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' }
];
cmp.set('v.mycolumns', [
    // Other column data here
    { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions, menuAlignment: 'left' } }
]);
```

In your case, you just need to change your code a bit:

```
{type: 'action', typeAttributes: {rowActions: [{label:'Edit',name:'edit_record'}]}
```

Comment: thank you, again save my day